# Completeness of A* Search

Tags: algorithm

I have been reading about the completeness of A* and I understand that it must be complete if it has a finite branching factor , but why it must be also complete when each edge weight is greater than 0 ?

Comment: Because if you have negative weights, you can't never ensure that you have the optimal path. There may be an extension of your path passing through these negative weighted branches. Or worse, there may be a cycle of negative weights, where your algorithm will loop forever.

Comment: I think you've made two errors in the transcription of this theorem. "A* is complete if it has finite branching factor and all weights are larger than some ε>0." You've replaced "and" with "or", and replaced "larger than some ε>0" with "positive". See my answer for why your statement of the theorem is false.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true that if the graph has finite branching factor and each edge weight is greater than zero then A* terminates.

For example, consider the graph with vertices `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, ... and a single vertex `*`. Let the weight of the edge between `i` and `i+1` be 1/2^i, and let the weight of the edge between `0` and `*` be 2. Let the heuristic be 0, so A* degenerates into Dijkstra's algorithm.

Then A* will not find (in finite time) the path from `0` to `*` -- it will explore the path along the natural numbers since the distance from `0` to `n` is always less than 2. So despite the fact that this graph has finite branching factor and positive edge weights, A* does not find the solution.

The correct statement of the theorem is: "If a graph has a finite branching factor and all weights are greater than some ε>0 then A* is complete." The proof is straightforward: if the path from the start to the end is of weight d, then in the worst case all vertices distance <= d are visited before the end node. But there can be at most finitely many of them because the path from the start node to each can consist of at most d/ε vertices.